# SQL Increment column value in select statement

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to write a `Select` statement that increments a `column` value by 50, but the range can end up being 200,000 so I can't do it all in a case statement manually.

Something similar to this, but instead of manually writing the `increments`

```
Select count(order_id) as order_count, 
   case when revenue between 0 and 50 then ‘$50’
        when order_value between 51 and 100 then ‘$100’
             else ‘over $101’
   end as revenue_bucket
from Orders
group by 2
```

Comment: So, a single column, and each row incremented by 50?

Comment: something like : revenue - (revenue % 50) + 50?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn your `revenue` into the bucket value, then make string out of it:

```
SELECT count(order_id) AS order_count, 
        '$' || ((((revenue - 0.01)/50)::int + 1) * 50)::text AS revenue_bucket
FROM Orders
GROUP BY 2;
```

This obviously runs well past $200,000.

Comment: This would sort `50` in the `51-100` bucket (easy fix: subtract 1 from revenue)

Comment: @Andomar Good point. Answer updated, but subtracting just a penny instead of a dollar.

Answer (score 1):

You can work with modulo to get this. Limit would be 101 in your example. All you have to do, is cast the result in a string and add the $ before it

```
Select count(order_id) as order_count, 
    case when revenue < limit then revenue - (revenue % 50) + 50
             else ‘over $101’
  end as revenue_bucket
from Orders
group by 2
```

Comment: Duh, you're right :)  I'll remove the comments in a sec +1

Comment: k, i was just wondering if i did something wrong, no problem^^

Answer (score 0):

You can round to the nearest 50 with `div` (integer division):

```
revenue div 50 * 50
```

To round up instead of down:

```
(revenue div 50 + 1) * 50
```

To include 50 in the next bracket (so 50 as $50 instead of $100):

```
((revenue-1) div 50 + 1) * 50
```

Example query:

```
select  revenue
,       concat('$', ((revenue-1) div 50 + 1) * 50) as revenue_bucket
from    YourTable
```

[See it working at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e30ba/2/0)

Answer (score 0):

figured out something similar

```
select floor((revenue+49)/50)*50 as revenue_bucket, 
       count(1) as order_count
from Orders 
group by 1;
```