# SQL: Increment row value when selected

Tags: php, sql, select, increment, amazon-rds

Within Amazon RDS, I have a table, `source`, in the form of

```
id | name | times_shown
------------------------
0  | matt | 0
1  | jeff | 0
2  | jake | 0
.  | ...  | .
.  | ...  | .
.  | ...  | .
```

I have a SQL query that randomly selects a row from this table

```
SELECT * FROM source ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;
```

Is there a way for me to modify this query so that when it selects a row, it also causes the value of the `times_shown` column to increment? If not, is there some other way, maybe an obscure column type or PHP SQL PDO driver setting, that would let me do this?

From my understanding, [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31558294/sql-increment-column-value-in-select-statement) asking something similar is about changing the results of the SELECT, rather than actually changing the value in the db as I am hoping to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What RDMS?  If MySQL, probably need to do in two parts, change your `SELECT` to `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` and then separately update the `times_shown` field

Take a look at: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html

And the example there:

```
SELECT counter_field FROM child_codes FOR UPDATE;
UPDATE child_codes SET counter_field = counter_field + 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

No. There is no magical functionality that allows you to update a row when selecting it.  You will need to update the row after the select is made.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question was answered quite a while ago, but just wanted to add that with PostgreSQL (you didn't say which RDBMS you were using) you can do it in one step using a Common Table Expression:

```
with updated_values as (
    update source set times_shown = times_shown + 1
    where id in (select id from sources order by random() limit 1)
    returning id, name, times_shown
)
select * from updated_values;
```

Comment: I was using MySQL, but thanks for the answer, I'm sure someone will find it useful in the future!